# SciFi book with deadly plague and father/son forced to find cure

Tags: story-identification, books

I think the main character's name is Benjamin. The king calls upon he and his father to find a cure to the deadly plague that's sweeping across the nation. Benjamin finds this chemical called something like "tintillium." I'm certain, however, that the chemical does not exist. This chemical causes hallucinations when it is inhaled and Benjamin creates a new world in which he is forced to play a Hunger Games-esque game in order to get the cure for the deadly plague.

I'm guessing publication to be around 2010, or so...

All help is appreciated in trying to find this title!

Comment: Does Benjamin create this world in his hallucination?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes.

Comment: If the chemical doesn't exist, how does it cause hallucinations?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It doesn't exist in the _real_ world. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Illusionarium](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062001051) by Heather Dixon

> What if the world holds more dangers—and more wonders—than we have
>   ever known? And what if there is more than one world? From Heather
>   Dixon, author of the acclaimed Entwined, comes a brilliantly conceived
>   adventure that sweeps us from the inner workings of our souls to the
>   far reaches of our imaginations.
>
> Jonathan is perfectly ordinary. But then—as every good adventure
>   begins—the king swoops into port, and Jonathan and his father are
>   enlisted to find the cure to a deadly plague. Jonathan discovers that
>   he's a prodigy at working with a new chemical called fantillium, which
>   creates shared hallucinations—or illusions. And just like that,
>   Jonathan is knocked off his path.

Comment: I looked at the cover of this book, and was immediately certain. Thank you very much for this!